# Properly format an ActiveRecord query with a subquery in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a working SQL query for Postgres v10.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (title) products.title, products.* 
    FROM "products" 
) subquery
WHERE subquery.active = TRUE AND subquery.product_type_id = 1
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

With the goal of the query to do a distinct based on the `title` column, then filter and order them. (I used the subquery in the first place, as it seemed there was no way to combine `DISTINCT ON` with `ORDER BY` without a subquery.

I am trying to express said query in ActiveRecord.

I have been doing

```
Product.select("*")
    .from(Product.select("DISTINCT ON (product.title) product.title, meals.*"))
    .where("subquery.active IS true")
    .where("subquery.meal_type_id = ?", 1)
    .order("created_at DESC")
```

and, that works! But, it's fairly messy with the string where clauses in there. Is there a better way to express this query with ActiveRecord/Arel, or am I just running into the limits of what ActiveRecord can express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the resulting ActiveRecord call can be improved.

But I would start improving with original SQL query first.

Subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (title) products.title, products.* FROM products
```

(I think that instead of `meals` there should be `products`?) has duplicate `products.title`, which is not necessary there. Worse, it misses ORDER BY clause. As PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) says:

> Note that the “first row” of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first

I would rewrite sub-query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (title) * FROM products ORDER BY title ASC
```

which gives us a call:

```
Product.select('DISTINCT ON (title) *').order(title: :asc)
```

In main query `where` calls use Rails-generated alias for the `subquery`. I would not rely on Rails internal convention on aliasing subqueries, as it may change anytime. If you do not take this into account you could merge these conditions in one `where` call with hash-style argument syntax.

The final result:

```
Product.select('*')
       .from(Product.select('DISTINCT ON (title) *').order(title: :asc))
       .where(subquery: { active: true, meal_type_id: 1 })
       .order('created_at DESC')
```